# Passing callback from JavaScript to Java (Android)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an app for Android using HTML5/JavaScript. Running into limitations, I want to call a function that is realized in the Java code from within JavaScript. To be more precise, I want to create a certain type of dialog. This is fairly easy (I will only give a rough outline/stub):

```
public class MyClass () {
    // other stuff

    public void createMyDialog (/* arguments */) {
        DialogBuilder builder = ...
        builder.setItems(myItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void OnClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                droidGap.loadUrl(/* what now? */);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then this class is revealed to JavaScript with

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
appView.addJavascriptInterface(myClass, "myClass");
```

So far so good. I can now access `window.myClass.createMyDialog()` from within JavaScript. *However*, what I'd like to do is pass a callback that will be called with the `which` variable as a parameter. This means having a signature like

```
public void createMyDialog (final String callback)
```

and calling it with something like

```
window.myClass.createMyDialog(
    function (which) {
        alert(which);
    }
);
```

I can get this to work my passing the function as a string (using `String()` around the function) and calling `appView.loadUrl("javascript:(" + callback + ")(" + which + ");");` from Java.
Never mind that this solution doesn't feel very clean, it has a big disadvantage – to finally come to the point. Because in JavaScript, I'm actually calling `createMyDialog` from within a class and I'd like to do somehting like this:

```
function myJSClass () {
    this.myVar = -1;

    this.myFunc = function () {
        window.myClass.createMyDialog(
            function (which) {
                this.myVar = which;
            }
        );
    }
}

var myObj = new myJSClass();
myObj.myFunc();
```

The problem now being that with the solution from above, `this` will refer to `window` rather than the class instance. This isn't a new problem, but none of the typical solutions (storing `var _this = this` outside the call and using `_this.myVar = which` or using `bind`) work as the context of `this` is just completely lost because the function will be called from Java.

I know that it has to be possible since the PhoneGap framework offers `navigator.notification.confirm` which pretty much does exactly what I want. What is the way to go here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not quite understanding how you are invoking createMyDialog().  In the callback function, if you replace "this.myVar = which;" with "console.log(which);" or "alert(which);", do you get the value of "which"?

Comment: Yes, the value of `which` is being passed correctly. Currently the problem is that I can't control in which context the callback is being executed. I can't use the `_this` trick as `var _this = this;` creates a variable local to the method, but callback is executed in a global context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should really [write a Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). We've already run into a number of Java/JS and JS/Java problems so you should take advantage of our tested code.

Second, you are going to need to run your dialog on the UI thread. If you don't there will be problems.

Third, if you want to call as specific success/error call back from Java when a dialog action has happened you can do that via the PluginResult class. If you set the success condition the success callback will be invoked and vice versa.

Check out the PG code for notification which contains examples on a number of dialogs:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/Notification.java;h=958ab26b842b41326523b9fa154aa8c71885c8ab;hb=HEAD

Comment: Hi, Simon. Man, you're everywhere. I will take a look into it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I switched everything to the plugin system. Working like a charm!

Comment: I didn't forget :) I used the same structure as in the Notification plugin you linked to.